# How to pass an extra option in ls using execv()?

Tags: c, linux, wildcard

I'm trying to execute this simple command `ls -1 *.c` using the execv() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
char *arr[3]={"ls","-1","*.c"};
execv("/bin/ls",arr);
}
```

The output I'm getting is

```
ls: cannot access *.c: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `char *arr[]={"ls","-1","*.c",NULL};` The pointer array needs a NULL sentinel, so that its length can be  determined.

Comment: The wildcards like `*` are interpreted by the shell, not by `ls`.

Comment: `char *arr[]={"ls","-1","*.c",NULL};` will give the same out put.

Comment: @user3133165 Yes, but it won't crash or fail with `EFAULT` or do even crazier things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a big problem in your code: `execv` can't tell how big the array you're passing it is. You absolutely need a terminating `NULL` element to mark the end:

```
char *arr[] = { "ls", "-1", "*.c", NULL };
```

OK, now that we have a valid `execv` invocation, we can deal with the `ls` error.

Calling `execv` like this is equivalent to running

```
'ls' '-1' '*.c'
```

on the command line (which would produce the same error).

When you do

```
ls -1 *.c
```

on the command line, `ls` never sees `*.c` because the shell expands wildcards and passes a list of matching filenames to `ls`.

If you want to replicate that in your C code, you have to do the same thing manually. See e.g. [`man glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) for a function that does most of the work. Here's an adapted example from the man page that shows the general principle:

```
glob_t globbuf;

globbuf.gl_offs = 2;
glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "ls";
globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-1";
execv("/bin/ls", globbuf.gl_pathv);
```

Comment: Do you need to free the allocated buffer in globbuf with `globfree(&globbuf);` afterwards?

Comment: @TomKuschel If `execv` is successful, there is no afterwards.

Comment: Why do I need `ls` as argument? Isn't it already present in the command with `execv("/bin/ls", globbuf.gl_pathv)`? Isn't it then built as `/bin/ls ls -l *.c` (*.c is replaced with the file list of globbuf).

Comment: @TomKuschel `/bin/ls` is the executable to run. By convention, programs expect their own name in `argv[0]` (the first argument).