# How to copy folders names inside a directory to a text file

Tags: c, unix

I'd like to know how can I copy folders names inside a directory to a text files.

I'm attempting to create a text file called studentList.txt which holds all the folders names inside a directory "./allStudents" which are the students names.

```
char* dir ="./allStudents";

int fd = open("studentlist.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0777);
    if (fd < 0) exit(-1);
    //dup is assigned '1' standard file descripter
    //which means any output sent to '1' will be written to studentlist.txt file
    //Closing the standard output file descriptor
    close(1);
    dup(fd);

    char **arguments = (char **) malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
    if (!arguments) exit(-1);

    //Using "ls" to generate a list of all students
    arguments[0] = "ls";
    arguments[1] = "-d"; // List only names of directories
    arguments[2] = dir;
    arguments[3] = NULL;

    //Output was redirected to studentlist.txt and should be written
    //Copying only the directories inside dir
    execvp("ls", arguments);

    //Closing the file descriptor of studentlist.txt
    close(fd);
```

The result from the following code shows the directory name in studentlist.txt

```
./allStudents
```

Instead, I want it to show the students names (which are the folders names inside allStudents directory)

```
Jack
Alex
Jason
```

Comment: `-d` does not tell `ls` to only list directories; it tells `ls` to treat directories like regular files and not list their contents. So `ls -d dir` lists only `dir`. To get a list of directories inside `dir`, you can either list its contents (e.g., with `-F` so that each directory is noted with a `/` after its name) and remove the entries that are not directories or use another command, like `find dir -depth 1 -type d`. Or you can explore other options like using system routines to traverse the directory tree.

Comment: From [the `ls` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) about the `-d` option: "list directories themselves, **not their contents**" (emphasis min). Perhaps [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) could be a better command to use? As in `find allStudents -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Comment: Or (as mentioned by @EricPostpischil) use functions to list directories in your own code? Like [`opendir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude actually -F seems to work. but it adds a "/" after  each name is there a possible way to make it disappear? I'd like to still use the "ls" command if possible, thanks.

Comment: @Nitzan Why use `ls`? Not even [tag:bash] programmers thinks it's a good idea to parse the output from `ls`. Using `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir` is also **a lot** simpler and **a lot** less error prone.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree with you, I just have an assignment and they requested that I do it with "ls" command somehow.

Comment: "somehow"? Would that include `system("ls -l allStudents | grep ^d > studentlist.txt");` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I use './allStudents > studentsList.txt' in the terminal it will definitely work, but If I try to use such commands in the program it will pop errors saying that I can only do it in the shell.

Comment: Are you saying that [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WzeKzjK8W) doesn't work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It appears to work but I'm trying to find a way to keep it with the format I posted using dup(), close(), open() etc.. if possible, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **lstat** for your purpose. This can also be done using **struct dirent** member - **d_type**, but this is supported by only few file systems. You can read man page for more info (**man readdir**). Here is an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
char *dir_name = "/home/atom/";
DIR *dp = NULL;
struct dirent *info = NULL;
char file_name[512] = {0};
struct stat sb;

dp = opendir(dir_name);
if (dp == NULL) {
    perror("opendir");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ( (info = readdir(dp)) ) {
    //printf("Name: %s\tType: %u\n",info->d_name,info->d_type);  // NOT SUPPORTED ON ALL FILE SYSTEMS
    sprintf(file_name, "%s/%s",dir_name,info->d_name);
    printf("Path: %s  --- ",file_name);

    if (lstat(file_name,&sb) == -1) {
        perror("lstat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    switch(sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
       case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
       case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
       case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
       case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
       case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
       case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
       case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
       default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Once you get name of all directories inside a directory, you can write them where ever you want.

Comment: OP has to use `ls`  somehow though.

Comment: Looks great but I have to use the 'ls' command with the format posted.

Comment: oh okay. I see in above code you have used the incorrect ls command. Your command should be *ls -d */*, if you want to display directory names in current directory. However this command will ONLY WORK on cmdline. Reason it won't work directly inside a C program is because of * character in command. For cmdline this is expanded by shell and is given to ls command. That we have to do manually inside our C code. You can do that using **glob**. Read its man page for more details. I am adding the code that would work for you:

Comment: `
           glob_t globbuf;
           globbuf.gl_offs = 2;
           glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
           glob("../*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS | GLOB_APPEND, NULL, &globbuf);
           globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "ls";
           globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-l";
           execvp("ls", &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]); `

Use this code to invoke your **ls** command. Rest all things you can keep as per your requirement. ** But do note that directory name will have / ** appended to them

Comment: The code above is not formatted properly. But you can see this post for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686987/how-to-pass-an-extra-option-in-ls-using-execv
Credit goes to its author for explaining it clearly.

Comment: For later improvement, prevent/detect buffer overflow in `sprintf(file_name, "%s/%s",dir_name,info->d_name);`.

Comment: Agreed @chux-ReinstateMonica. We should have used snprintf. BTW this was just for POC purpose